# Access connected MTP device without receiving USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED Intent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, usb, android-3.0-honeycomb

I´m working on some application which uses Media Transfer Protocol to read Photos from a Camera connected to my Android Tablets USB host (Android 3.1, Acer Iconia Tab A500).

I found some tutorials describing how to work with USB and I got copying from USB camera to SD-Card already working.

There is only one problem I have: All the tutorials wait for USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED-Intent and then open a UsbDeviceConnection for communicating with the device that is sent within the intents Bundle.

So I would like to be able to manually start an activity which accesses USB - WITHOUT receiving this intent.
The Problem now is, that I cannot open an USBConnection like this

```
UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
```

It simply returns null. 
If I re-plugin the device and select my Activity as Intent receiver, it works fine.
I think this must be because of the IntentReceiver having some exclusive permissions on the USB device.

My Manifest looks like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

So one example: What if a user has set Galery as default for USB devices. How can I access the USB device in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the USB Host mode API guide documentation to be highly useful in this area.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#discovering-d

The most important note is that if you have NOT received a UsbDevice from an activity, then you will need to request permission to communicate with it. This process is described in the link provided.